How to solve this 2nd order Dirac Delta ODE
Any help how to solve this ODE to get $g(t)$:
$$\left( \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2}+ q^2 - \frac{2}{(2+3 t)^2}  \right) g(t) = \delta(t-z) $$
I wonder if the delta function requires any techniques in solving. I tried to solve by Wolfram Alpha but it doesn’t give a solution, while it gives a solution for WolframAlpha :
$$\left( \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2}+ q^2 - \frac{2}{t^2}  \right) g(t) = \delta(t-z) $$

Define $\tau=2+3t$ and $f(\tau)=g\bigl((\tau-2)/3)\bigr)$, then the function $f$ satisfies a differential equation
$$\left(9\frac{d^2}{d\tau^2}+q^2-\frac{2}{\tau^2}\right)f(\tau)=3\delta(\tau-2-3z),$$
for which you know the solution (see Wolfram Alpha).
